# Can we followup and offer freelance work?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

If I asked a question, and then learn the answer is more difficult than I can handle, I may instead want to hire a freelancer to implement an algorithm for me rather than write it on my own and screw up.

Clearly, those who answered my question are suitable, since they have demonstrated knowledge (and it's small enough that I don't want to go to careers). Is it acceptable to followup with a comment and ask them to email me about doing freelance work (if they don't have contact info listed in their profile)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Please be polite, and delete your (brief!) inquiry after they contact you (or the need is no longer present).  Don't spam all the people who answered, either.